# Active/current (1-5%) and historical records in same table: index or partitioning?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, index-tuning

I am trying to discover the correct architecture for the following situation. An application stores 'source data' in multiple tables. Each of these 'source data' tables contains *actual, current, active* records, as well as *old, historical* records. There will be a maximum of about a 100 *historical* 'sets' of data (older data will be cleaned up). Data is loaded in the 'source data tables' once per day or less. The data is otherwise never updated (no OLTP), only read.

95% of the time, queries are executed only on the *active* records. These queries must be executed almost as fast as if they were the only records in the table. It's ok if queries on the old/historical records are a bit slower (say, a cost increased with a factor 5-10 max).

I currently implemented this as follows:

- All 'source data' tables contain a column `SRC_CURRENT` with value 0 or 1. This column contains a bitmap index (but I've tried with a regular index too).
- All 'source data' tables contain a column `SRC_DATE` with the (truncated) date of the set of data. This column contains a regular index.
- All queries on all of these 'source data' tables always include either `SRC_CURRENT = 1`, or `SRC_CURRENT = 0 AND SRC_DATE = <date>`
- The `SRC_CURRENT` flag is set correctly each time a new set of data is inserted.

But the performance isn't what I expected. What I'm looking for is a way to let the CBO know that the `SRC_CURRENT` column only contains a value of 1 in about 1-5% of the rows, and that in that case he can limit the query to only this small subset. If a value of 0 is supplied (95-99% of rows), then he can, of course, just ignore this index and rely on the `SRC_DATE` index instead to select only the appropriate subset.

Can this be solved using only indexes, do I need partitioning, or is what I'm trying to do simply impossible and should I for instance resort to 2 separate source tables of each type (a table containing the active rows, and a table and a `_HIS` table) and duplicate all queries, with the application selecting the correct query ?

I'm using Oracle 9i, but if there's a solution to this problem available only in later versions, feel free to mention it too, for future reference.

**EDIT**

I did a test with partitioning one of the tables on the `SRC_CURRENT` column. This does seem to fix it, both when targeting `SRC_CURRENT = 1` as well as when targeting `SRC_CURRENT = 0 AND SRC_DATE = <date>`. Is this the proper approach ?

Comment: Did you tried index like this: `create index on table_name (src_current, src_date);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments, I seem to get the best results for both use cases (both on actual data, as well as on historical sets of data), when I **partition the tables on SRC_CURRENT** and create all other indexes on the tables as **local indexes**. I get times of ~4-6ms when querying the *actual* data, even on tables containing 1M+ records. On *historical* data, the queries take about ~10-50ms, which is still very acceptable in my situation.

The CBO currently chooses to skip the index on SRC_DATE (I haven't tested, but it might choose to use this index once there is a larger number of historical sets of data).

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning should work better than index if the number of rows is large. If the query needs to scan only one partition, it is more efficient than finding current rows through index.

If `SRC_CURRENT` is updated to 0 when newer rows are loaded, you need to enable row movement for the table. This will allow rows to move from current partition to historical partition.

Alternatively, if current rows are always the most recent rows, you could range-partition the table by date. This would allow you to clear expired rows very fast by running `drop partition` for the oldest partition. This will also benefit queries against historical data that access a range of dates but not the whole history.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted the answer, but it seems to me, since you're constantly aging out the active rows, you could simply create a function based index on the `SRC_CURRENT` column. It'd be something like this:

```
create index src_current_active_fbidx on <table>(decode(src_current, 1, 1, null));
```

This will create a compacted index of only the rows with a 1 value. As long as you keep this 1 value at 1-5% by aging out rows, you'll see great performance.

Not that partitioning won't work, but it does cost extra, while function based indexes do not.

For reference, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg06idx.htm (9i version), scroll down to "When to Use Function-Based Indexes".

Again, I know you already accepted an answer, but I wanted to throw this out since you seem open-minded about possible options.